# Auto.Arima Plot X-Axis

Tags: r, r-markdown, forecasting, arima

I'm currently trying to conduct a forecast of Facebook Stock prices using data from Yahoo Finance, and I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is the label on the x-axis of the auto-arima forecast plot.

Here is what I have so far:

```
fb <- c("FB")%>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2013-01-01",
         to = "2014-01-1")
fb %>% tail(10)
fit <- auto.arima(fb$close, ic="bic")
fit.forecast <- forecast(fit, h=20)
fit.forecast
plot(fit.forecast)
```

This produces the correct prediction that I was looking for, but the x-axis goes from 0-250, instead of by date, which I'm looking to do. Is there any way to accomplish this change in label?

[Here is what my plot looks like for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUyZz.png)